# Reaching an element type list in the dictionary and operations with it

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, duplicates

I'm stuck with a question about getting elements from a dictionary, which consists of lists. Task here is to get unique values from ids list, the answer should be: `[213, 15, 54, 119, 98, 35]`. I've understood that I should use an `.intersection(set)`, however, I've spend a lot of hours trying to cut data from this dictionary to make them look like set.

```
ids = {'user1': [213, 213, 213, 15, 213], 
       'user2': [54, 54, 119, 119, 119], 
       'user3': [213, 98, 98, 35]}
```

All I've got is this, but I'm so nervous that I can't see any solution anymore, that's why I ask to help

```
for items in ids.items():
  sets=set(items[1])
print(sets)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `|` union operator.

```
out=set()
for val in ids.values():
    out=out|set(val)

list(out)
# [15, 35, 54, 98, 119, 213]
```

Or you can use `union` method.

```
out=set() #Suggested by @schwobaseggl 
for val in ids.values():
    out=out.union(val)
```

Set comprehension

```
{i for val in ids.values() for i in val}
```

Comment: if you use the `union` method, you don't need to convert `val` to a set

Comment: Oh I recommended the same set comprehension answer. Did not see you did the same. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @RoadRunner Actually we both posted it at the same. ;)

Comment: @Ch3steR Yeah it seems so. It makes more sense to just add it your answer.

Comment: @Ch3steR That is probably quite slow. Would have to test it however.

Comment: @Ch3steR Do not use `sum` to concatenate lists. It has quadratic complexity.

Comment: @RoadRunner When compared to set comp and `chain.from_iterable` it will be slow I guess. It's better not to add to the question then.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Noted. Good point.

Comment: I've also flagged this question as a duplicate, which without suprise recommends the set comprehension solution :).

Comment: @RoadRunner I too voted to close it as a duplicate of what you suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Get the dictionary values, flatten the resulting nested list with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and build a `set`:

```
from itertools import chain

set(chain.from_iterable(ids.values()))
#{15, 35, 54, 98, 119, 213}
```